# Easiest way to return output with all combinations for a huge table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a new to sql and have this question... assume that there is a table with 90 columns and 200 rows , whats the easiest way to write a query to select and fetch all combinations of data? say for Instance row 34 and column 78, row 89 and column 2 and many more. So instead of writing a query for every combination individually is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: What's use case here? it does not make much sense to me. Also, do you have primary key(hope so)? Or how are you gone identify exact row?

Comment: Write it using some programming language, I think it is impossible or really hard to do it in MySQL

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You should give an example table (with e.g. 3 or 4 columns and a few rows) and then show the output you want to get.

Comment: It’s just really unlikely that a well designed table would have as many as 90 columns, or as few as 200 rows

Comment: Also, you say "Instead of writing a query for every combination individually". What would one of these queries look like? It would give us a better idea of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
select * from table_name
```

Comment: Let me rephrase the question properly. I want to write a query where I am able to get the output of every combination say for Instance row 34 and column 78, row 89 and column 2 and many more. So instead of writing a query for every combination individually is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: @anusha - edit your question with that additional information

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
SELECT variant_id, attr_id
FROM YouTable
GROUP BY variant_id, attr_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`Inner join` performs the cartesian product of two columns. Say for example TableA and TableB performing [inner join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) on them results in their combination of values.

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
```

This gives the combination of `OrderID` and `CustomerName` values.

Hope it helps !